# How to downgrade gcc 9.4.0 to 9.3.0 in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, gcc

I just installed ubuntu 20.04 and gcc. The default gcc version is 9.4.0. How to downgrade it from 9.4.0 to 9.3.0?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: You may install any gcc version you want for your own use, but don't change the system default gcc or things may break unexpectedly.

Comment: thanks for you comments. I was trying to compile OpenFoam software and got the error(/POSIX.o] Error 1).  I checked documentation and would like to install my own gcc, 9.3.0 for a test.